# R Regex Matching to Remove Commented Script from HTML

Tags: regex, r, web-scraping

Good evening all.

Got myself stuck trying to clean up some text from an HTML page that I've scraped as part of a corpus builder.

The text (stored in `fullText`) currently looks like...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

/* */
if (ads.isMobile()) { do something scripty in here }
/* */

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

I want to remove everything inside, and including the `/*  */` delimiters leaving just the *lorem ipsum* text (and yes I know they are a terrible choice but the HTML isn't mine).

I've found that the regex `\/\*\s\s\*\/(.|[\r\n])*?\/\*\s\s\*\/` does the job in an online regex editor, but NOT in R.

```
> regex    <- "\/\*\s\s\*\/(.|[\r\n])*?\/\*\s\s\*\/"
> fullText <- gsub(regex,"",fullText, perl=TRUE)

Error: '\/' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "\/"
```

Anyone got a thought on how to modify the regex here?

Comment: I don't know R, but given the error it looks like it doesn't accept redundant escapes. `/` doesn't need to be escaped in regex, so try replacing `\/` with `/`.

Comment: In `R` you need a double backslash "\\" because you have to escape the \ itself in order to let `R` know that the backslash should be interpreted literally.

Comment: Give `regex <- "/\\*[[:space:]]+\\*/[[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]*/\\*[[:space:]]+\\*/"` a try on your corpus. If it works, I'll post it as an answer. No need for a `perl=TRUE` with that one, btw.

Comment: Of note, you might have been better of using `rvest` to extract only the `html_text` elements from the file (as that would ignore all `<script>` tags. If you post the HTML, it'd be an easy example to show. Parsing is almost always a better way to go than regexes when it comes to HTML.

Comment: This regex worked for me and seems simpler: `regex="\\n/\\* \\*/.*/\\* \\*/\\n"`. Also no need for `perl=TRUE` here.

Comment: Why wouldn't `"[/*](.*)"` work for `/*` to the end? Or `"[/*](.*)[/*]"` for just between `/*` and `*/` inclusive

Comment: That's even better. It leaves in an extra blank line before an after, so you could remove those at the beginning and end as well.

Comment: Is the `Duis ...` paragraph supposed to stay?

Comment: This is not defined well. What happens when there is an odd number of `/* */` scattered about ? And that scripty stuff `v='/* */';`

Answer (score 4):

I find this alot easier to do using `strsplit` ...

```
x <- strsplit(fullText, '\\s*/\\*(?s).*\\*/\\s*', perl=T)[[1]]
cat(paste0(x[1], "\n\n", x[2]))
```

Outputs ...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: @BarneyC - I suggest you use this answer.  It will be more general and easier.